# AzCopy upload file for Linux

Tags: linux, azure, azcopy

I'm trying to upload a sample file to Azure from my Ubuntu machine using AzCopy for Linux but I keep getting the below error no matter what permission/ownership I change to.

```
$ azcopy     --source ../my_pub     --destination https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer     --dest-key account-key    
Incomplete operation with same command line detected at the journal directory "/home/jmis/Microsoft/Azure/AzCopy", do you want to resume the operation? Choose Yes to resume, choose No to overwrite the journal to start a new operation. (Yes/No) Yes
[2017/11/18 22:06:24][ERROR] Error parsing source location "../my_pub": Failed to enumerate directory /home/jmis/my_pub/ with file pattern *. Cannot find the path '/home/jmis/my_pub/'.
```

I have digged over the internet to find solutions, without having a luck I eventually ended up asking a question here.

Comment: Thanks but I have tampered with the dest key by addings some arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this script to upload **single** file with Azcopy(Linux):

```
azcopy \
    --source /mnt/myfiles \
    --destination https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ \
    --dest-key <key> \
    --include abc.txt
```

Use `--include` to specify which file you want to upload, here a example, please check it:

```
root@jasonubuntu:/jason# pwd
/jason
root@jasonubuntu:/jason# ls
test1


root@jasonubuntu:/jason# azcopy --source /jason/ --destination https://jasondisk3.blob.core.windows.net/jasonvm/ --dest-key m+kQwLuQZiI3LMoMTyAI8K40gkOD+ZaT9HUL3AgVr2KpOUdqTD/AG2j+TPHBpttq5hXRmTaQ== --recursive  --include test1
Finished 1 of total 1 file(s).                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[2017/11/20 07:45:57] Transfer summary:                                                                                                                                                                                        
-----------------
Total files transferred: 1
Transfer successfully:   1
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         0
Elapsed time:            00.00:00:02
root@jasonubuntu:/jason#
```

More information about Azcopy on Linux, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux#file-upload).

Comment: The mistake I was doing was ignoring the `--exclude` flag which is a mandate for uploading single file. Works like a charm now ! Thanks @Jason Ye - MSFT

Comment: azcopy linux documentation "single file upload" does NOT mention any need for --exclude or --include keys, just clean source and destination pointer to a file, like with any other such tool. But it does not work that way, it only works if you split --source to the folder and "include" as file.

Answer (score 3):

Although AzCopy was having issues for Linux I'm able to do the above operation seamlessly with Azure CLI. The below code listed on [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli) helped me do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A simple Azure Storage example script

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=<storage_account_name>
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=<storage_account_key>

export container_name=<container_name>
export blob_name=<blob_name>
export file_to_upload=<file_to_upload>
export destination_file=<destination_file>

echo "Creating the container..."
az storage container create --name $container_name

echo "Uploading the file..."
az storage blob upload --container-name $container_name --file $file_to_upload --name $blob_name

echo "Listing the blobs..."
az storage blob list --container-name $container_name --output table

echo "Downloading the file..."
az storage blob download --container-name $container_name --name $blob_name --file $destination_file --output table

echo "Done"
```

Going forward I will be using the Cool Azure CLI which is Linux compliant and Simple too.